# Truncated random variable and convergence in distribution

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics

Say $\{z_n\}$ is a collection of random variables which converges to the standard normal $z$ in distribution. $A$ is a fixed positive constant. How to show that $z_n\mathbb{1}_{\{z_n\leq A\}}$ converges to $z\mathbb{1}_{\{z\leq A\}}$ in distribution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall that the followings are equivalent:

1. $X_n \Rightarrow X$ ($X_n$ converges to $X$ in distribution).
2. $F_{X_n}(x) \to F_X(x)$ for all point of continuity $x$ of $F_X$.
3. $F_{X_n}(x) \to F_X(x)$ for all $x$ in a dense subset of $\mathbb{R}$.

Now assume that $Z_n \Rightarrow Z$ for $Z \sim \mathcal{N}(0, 1)$ and $g(z) = z \mathbf{1}_{\{z \leq A\}}$. We show $g(Z_n) \Rightarrow g(Z)$ by verifying Condition 3 of the above equivalence.

*Proof.* For any $x \in \mathbb{R}$, we split $F_{g(Z_n)}(x)$ into two parts as follows:

\begin{align*}
F_{g(Z_n)}(x)
&= \mathbf{P}(Z_n \mathbf{1}_{\{Z_n \leq A\}} \leq x) \\
&= \mathbf{P}(Z_n \leq x, Z_n \leq A) + \mathbf{P}(0 \leq x, Z_n > A) \\
&= \mathbf{P}(Z_n \leq \min\{x, A\}) + \mathbf{P}(Z_n > A) \mathbf{1}_{\{0 \leq x\}} \\
&= F_{Z_n}(\min\{x, A\}) + (1 - F_{Z_n}(A)) \mathbf{1}_{\{0 \leq x\}}
\end{align*}

Since $F_Z$ is continuous everywhere, it follows that $F_{Z_n}(z) \to F_Z(z)$ for all $z \in \mathbb{R}$. Hence

\begin{align*}
\lim_{n\to\infty} F_{g(Z_n)}(x)
&= F_{Z}(\min\{x, A\}) + (1 - F_{Z}(A)) \mathbf{1}_{\{0 \leq x\}} \\
&= F_{g(Z)}(x)
\end{align*}

and the desired conclusion follows.

---

**Addendum.** In fact, a much more general statement holds:

> [**Continuous mapping theorem.**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_mapping_theorem) Let $g : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be a Borel-measurable function, and let $D_g$ be the set of all points of discontinuity of $g$. If $X_n \Rightarrow X$ and $\mathbf{P}(X \in D_g) = 0$, then $ g(X_n) \Rightarrow g(X) $.

The [standard proof](https://www.stat.cmu.edu/%7Earinaldo/Teaching/36752/S18/Scribed_Lectures/Apr5.pdf) hinges on [Skorokhod's representation theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skorokhod%27s_representation_theorem). (See Theorem 3.2.10 of [Durrett](https://services.math.duke.edu/%7Ertd/PTE/PTE5_011119.pdf) as well.)